# gitlab-ci terraform state lock file eradication

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci

While trying to migrate my backend config to use the new state storage with gitlab, I have run into this glorious problem:  My state is locked.

- I cannot force-unlock the state because the backend needs to be reinitialized
- I cannot force-unlock -force the state unlock because the backend needs to be reinitialized
- I cannot set up the backend with -lock=false because the same credentials that started this entire mess cannot seem to push things other than toxic lock tokens:

```
Error: Error copying state from the previous "local" backend to the newly configured
"http" backend:
    Failed to upload state: POST http://internal.host/api/v4/projects/14/terraform/state/project-name giving up after 3 attempts
```

I'm at my patience's end.  I did try to check whether the chatter in /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production_json.log delivers something relevant or not, and came away no more sure and little less sane for it.

Is there a `sudo pretty-please-with-sugar-on-top-clean-the-fn-lock` command that doesn't have any gatekeeping on it?

Comment: Note:  I've worked around this issue temporarily by using a different URL for the locking.  I'd still like to know a sure-fire let-go-a-my-ear method for definitively killing that lock.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same problem while migrating the terraform state files from s3 to gitlab.
I caused the problem because I had a typo in the backend_config unlock_address and I inserted Control+C while init was still running.
The terraform init did not ask me to migrate states from s3 to gitlab, but I got locked  and force unlock would not work in any way.

The solution I came with:

1. Configure backend.tf to use as unlock address the previously used lock_address and re-initialize terraform.
2. Terraform plan should work fine now.
3. Reconfigure backend.tf to continue with state migration. Re-initialize terraform state URLs with the ones you want by migrating again.

For example, this is the terraform init I used where the desired adress was <TF_State_Name>  and I had a typo <TF_State_Name_B> .
I interrupted with control+C:

```
terraform init \
 -backend-config="address=https://<gitlab_url>/api/v4/projects/<ProjectID>/terraform/state/<TF_State_Name>" \ 
 -backend-config="lock_address=https://<gitlab_url>/api/v4/projects/<ProjectID>/terraform/state/<TF_State_Name>/lock" \    
 -backend-config="unlock_address=https://<gitlab_url>/api/v4/projects/<ProjectID>/terraform/state/<TF_State_Name_B>/lock" \
 -backend-config="username=<user>" \     
 -backend-config="password=<password>" \   
 -backend-config="lock_method=POST" \    
 -backend-config="unlock_method=DELETE" \
 -backend-config="retry_wait_min=5"
```

And this is how I re-configured terraform init in order to by-pass the lock.

```
terraform init \
 -backend-config="address=https://<gitlab_url>/api/v4/projects/<ProjectID>/terraform/state/<TF_State_Name_B>" \ 
 -backend-config="lock_address=https://<gitlab_url>/api/v4/projects/<ProjectID>/terraform/state/<TF_State_Name_B>/lock" \    
 -backend-config="unlock_address=https://<gitlab_url>/api/v4/projects/<ProjectID>/terraform/state/<TF_State_Name_B>/lock" \
 -backend-config="username=<user>" \     
 -backend-config="password=<password>" \   
 -backend-config="lock_method=POST" \    
 -backend-config="unlock_method=DELETE" \
 -backend-config="retry_wait_min=5"
```

Finally, you should reconfigure to the desired address.

Answer (score 0):

## Feature Request

I opened a feature request for this functionality upstream,

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/34172#issue-1971224552

Comment: you mean here for upstream, right?  https://github.com/opentofu/opentofu/issues